# Order rows chronologically by using Time Value provided in a column - Do this for many dates

Tags: excel

I have a sheet which has Dates as first column and time as second column. Then in other columns more details (which are not part of the problem).

The problem is on a given date there are "n" number of rows (each with same date in 1st column). BUT, the time is not chronological.

Say, on 7th Jan there are 4 rows of data with times such as

```
7-jan-2016  14:25:33 x y z 
7-jan-2016  10:43:51 v t s 
7-jan-2016  13:01:02 h m p
7-jan-2016  12:48:15 l p l
9-jan-2016  problem same as above
```

I need to rearrange the rows chronologically FOR EACH DATE. Such that above looks like this:

```
7-jan-2016  10:43:51 v t s 
7-jan-2016  12:48:15 l p l
7-jan-2016  13:01:02 h m p
7-jan-2016  14:25:33 x y z 
9-jan-2016  no more problems.. and as above..
```

How can I achieve this without manually cut-pasting rows that are in 1000's.

Comment: go to DATA ---> Sort, then choose Column A in ascending order and add another rule, then sort column B in order?

Comment: thanks, Scott. now that i know the answer i feel why i even posted the question :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Sort by the first column, then select `Add Level` and sort by the second column.